# Unable to import lodash

Tags: node.js, typescript, lodash

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm facing a problem while trying to load lodash.

Here is my code :

```
///<reference path="../../typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts"/>    
///<reference path="../interfaces/IScheduler.ts"/>

import _ = require('lodash');

module MyModule {

  export class LeastUsedScheduler implements IScheduler {
     /// CODE HERE
  }
}
```

I tried replacing the import line by :

```
import * as _ from lodash;
```

In the two cases I get :

```
"error| Cannot find name 'IScheduler'."
```

When I remove the import directive it compiles perfectly but _ is undefined at runtime.

I also tried to put the import inside the module without success.

I'm sorry It must be a very dumb question but I can't figure it out.

Thank you

**EDIT :**

I understood the problem. Referencing the typing for lodash created the variable `_` in the scope. That's why it compiles fine without the import line. The problem is referencing the typing does not really import lodash. That's why it fails at runtime.

When I import lodash the compilation fails because lodash is already in the scope.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: The import statement needs quotes around the module name. `lodash` should be `"lodash"`.

Comment: should it be: `var _ =  require('lodash');`?

Comment: @thoughtrepo using quotes does not changed anything but thank you for your comment.

Comment: @BrandonSmith I tried your proposition and I get this : ` Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_' must be of type 'LoDashStatic', but here has type 'any'.` With your proposition I understood more the problem. I will edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% about the issue but can you try the following and let me know how it goes?

```
///<reference path="../../typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../interfaces/IScheduler.ts"/>

import _ = require("lodash");

export class LeastUsedScheduler implements IScheduler {
  doSomething(){
    _.each([],function name(parameter) {
        // ...
    });
  }
}
```

When compiled it looks like:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var LeastUsedScheduler = (function () {
    function LeastUsedScheduler() {
    }
    LeastUsedScheduler.prototype.doSomething = function () {
        _.each([], function name(parameter) {
            throw new Error("Not implemented yet");
        });
    };
    return LeastUsedScheduler;
})();
exports.LeastUsedScheduler = LeastUsedScheduler;
```

If you import the module `import _ = require("lodash");` but you don't use it, TypeScript will remove the import (I added the doSoemthing method for that reason).

## Update: Why it didn't work?

The problem was that the `module` keyword is used to declare an internal module. At the same time the code was loading an external module. You should avoid mixing internal and external modules. You can learn more about the difference between internal and external modules at http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-internal-and-external-modules/.

Also, if you use internal modules avoid using the `module` keyword as it is deprecated and you should use the `namespace` keyword instead.

Comment: I tried your proposition but I get the same error and even a new one : "error TS2305: Module '"lodash"' has no exported member '_'"

Comment: I already had something in my class. I just removed it to make my post clearer

Comment: when I used your solution and removed my module declaration it worked ! But I really want it to be in my module how can I do this ? Am I doing it wrong  ?

Comment: Happy to help, I have added an update to explain why it didn't work

Comment: I didn't know about namespaces. Than you !